# Scatter clusters in Stata 12

Tags: plot, graph, stata, scatter

I've created two different clusters, one using kmeans (partitioning method) and one using complete linkage (hierarchical).

**The clusters using the hierarchical method:**

```
cluster completelinkage area age, name(hcm_5) measure(L2)
cluster generate c1 = group(5), name(hcm_1)
```

**The clusters using the partitioning method:**

```
cluster kmeans area age, k(5) name(pcm_1)
```

This creates two different cluster. Now i want to visually see the clusters created. I want to do a scatter and make it show different color depending of the value of pcm_1 and c1. However, I can only create a scatter checking for one statement.

Ex:

```
scatter ycoord xcoord if pcm_1==1, mcolor(red)
scatter ycoord xcoord if pcm_1==2, mcolor(green)
... 
scatter ycoord xcoord if pcm_1==5, mcolor(purple)
```

How do I get all these scatters in the same one graph, with different colors depending on the value of the variable in each observation?

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic idea of how to do it:

```
ssc install labutil
sysuse auto 
separate price , by(rep78) gen(price_)
labvarch price_*, after("== ")
tw scatter price_* weight
drop price_*
```

If you store each cluster's y values in their own variable, it makes it easier to plot them all at once.

You can also do it by hand like this:

```
tw (scatter price weight if rep78==1) (scatter price weight if rep78==2) (scatter price weight if rep78==3) (scatter price weight if rep78==4) (scatter price weight if rep78==5)
```

Comment: `separate price , by(rep78) gen(price_) veryshortlabel` renders `labvarch` redundant here. Documented at http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0023